# Can someone please explain this: 都没吃饭吗

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I was watching a drama and in the scene, the coach was speaking to her team:

> Coach: 希望每个队员都能拿出最好的状态。能不能做到 (I know all of you can do your best。 Can you do that?)
>
> Team: 能！(Yes!)
>
> Coach: **都没吃饭吗** (Not loud enough!)

Can someone please explain to me why "都没吃饭吗" can mean this? Would you ever use that to ask if your friends have eaten?
Thank you!!

Comment: Hint: *haven’t eaten* implies no energy, hence lack of enthusiasm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the coach thinks the players are not energetic enough as if they were hungry.

This sentence can only be used in some situations:

- a coach blames the players being not energetic enough
- an officer blames the soldiers being not powerful enough
- fighter ridicule the opponent being so weak

or similar. Always considered as a blaming or ridiculing.

If you ask a friend about eating, it would be “吃饭了吗？” instead of “没吃饭吗？”.

Comment: Very helpful explanation, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The expression can be used every time that one thinks another doesn't take their necessary efforts to achieve something as if saying: *you can't make it because you haven't eaten your meal so you don't have that energy*.

It can be used as a *hurry-up* to urge someone to put more energy/effort on something.

It can be a blame, ironic, etc depending on how you use it.

However, 没吃饭吗 can also be taken literally.  We should understand it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you!! It makes a lot more sense now.